# Today Extension not working in debug or testflight mode

Tags: ios, debugging, widget, testflight, today-extension

On my device Today's extension is not fetching data from coredata while opening from debug mode or installing application from testflight. The same build if I install or update from Appstore Today's extension works fine.

Please let me know if there is anything to be handled in order to make it work same in all modes.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could be the certificate issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But issue is not with certificate, I have configured all certificates properly and I am able to run widget on my device. Problem is while fetching data from Coredata nothing is fetched. Same code if moved to live it is working properly.